# What is happening here in Spark Code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sequencefile

```
 val jsonString = sc.sequenceFile[Long,String](paths).map(x => {
      x._2
    })
```

The paths variable has csv of locations for some text files.
What exactly is the code mapping here?
can some explain me what is happening here. i am bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

`sc.sequenceFile` reads *Hadoop Sequence Files* which are flat files storing key-value pairs (see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile). It produces a `RDD[(Long, String)]` - an RDD where each record is a key-value pair (of type `Tuple2[Long, String]`). Then, the mapping simply maps each pair to the *value* only (using `Tuple2._2`).

The resulting `jsonString` is an `RDD[String]`.

The map operation can be replaced with a few equivalent calls that may or may not be clearer:

```
// Using the implicit PairRDDFunctions.values:
val jsonString = sc.sequenceFile[Long,String](paths).values

// Using map with anonymous argument:
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 2))).map(_._2)

// Using map with pattern matching: 
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 2))).map {
  case (key, value) => value
}
```

Comment: my paths variable has some thing like "/data/1.json,/data/2.json" when it converts to sequence file what is happening there? is it reading the data inside the json file and mapping the key value?

Comment: Does this code work? Because the `sequenceFile` _assumes_ that the paths it receives point to sequence files and not json files. It shouldn't be used to read Jsons, and I would assume it would simply fail. If what you're really asking is "how to read json files using Spark" - well, that's a different question for which I'm sure you can find the answer on SO.

Comment: It fails. now i understand. i was asked to work on existing code where someone wrote and left the company. Thank you very much it is clear now.